# Culture problem reading formatted decimal values

Tags: .net, text, culture

I have an console application (that also is run as a service when deployed). I'm reading values that originates from a text file. The problem is that I can't get the decimal values to work properly.

They are formatted in a "swedish way", like this `3,4` which in "english" formatting is `3.4`.

When I use:

```
Decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo("sv"), out result);
```

I get a

> Culture 'sv' is a neutral culture. It
>   cannot be used in formatting and
>   parsing and therefore cannot be set as
>   the thread's current culture.

exception.

If I try:

```
Decimal.TryParse(value, out result);
```

The value gets trucated (3,4 becomes 3).

Is there a way to read these formatted values (which can be integers also) in a robust and safe way, regardless of the settings in the operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You need to use "sv-SE"](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)

"sv" defaults to "sv-EN" you need to specify a country then a language in this case.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  decimal result;
  Decimal.TryParse("2,3", NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo("sv-SE"), 
                   out result); 
  Console.WriteLine(result);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Result **2.3**